# "English" pronounced as /ˈɪŋlɪʃ/ ING-LISH

Tags: pronunciation

According to Wiktionary, in Old English the term [**Englisc**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Englisc) still shows in its pronunciation the sound */g/*, so how come it is not pronounced by some speakers according to the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary*? Any other terms where a similar phenomenon appears?

Comment: There are lots of different dialects and regional variations for lots of words.

Comment: The OED gives 117 historical spellings for "English". All of them contain "g". The standardisation of English spelling did not start to take place until the 17th century. In broad terms, the writer wrote as he pronounced it, i.e. with a "g" sound: /ˈɪŋ(ɡ)lɪʃ/. The brackets indicate that the sound is light following the nasal "ng - /ŋ/". You may not hear the (g) but native speakers do and they pronounce it. In British English the 'g' is particularly pronounced in the East Midlands accent but exists overall. Other examples occur where {vowel+ng} occurs within a word - the obvious being "angle".

Comment: To my ear (and palate) it's virtually impossible to pronounce English as /ˈɪŋlɪʃ/. When spoken quickly the release of the /ŋ/ to form the /l/ necessitates at least a passing formation of the /g/. But why are you resurrecting Old English as a rubric for current pronunciation? Should we pronounce initial /ge/ as /ye/? Or all /f/ between vowels as /v/? The list goes on.

Comment: It's English.  You can pronounce it any way you want!

Answer (score 4):

In Old English, [ŋ] was always followed by either [k] or [g]. Modern English words that end in [ŋ] without [g], like *sing,* show the result of a change of word-final [ŋg] to [ŋ] (this change did not occur to completion in all dialects).

Word-internal [ŋg] mostly remained (as in *finger, anger*), but an originally word-final *-ng-* that becomes word-internal only as the result of the addition of certain suffixes is pronounced [ŋ] (e.g. *singing, singer*).

The *-ng-* in *English* is not word-final, and *-lish* is not a suffix here, so it isn't expected to be pronounced [ŋ] according to the pronunciation patterns of the most commonly described dialects. However, some dialects or speakers may have a more extensive change of original [ŋg] to [ŋ]. The distinction between [ŋg] and [ŋ] is historically recent, not marked in the spelling, and not especially important for marking contrasts between words: these factors might make it easier for variation between [ŋg] and [ŋ] to exist for some words.