# Why does "singer" have /ŋ/ and "longer" have /ŋg/?

Tags: pronunciation

The word "[singer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/singer)" is pronounced as /ˈsɪŋ.ər/ having **/ŋ/** and not **/ŋg/** in Standard Englishes. On the other hand, the word "[longer](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/longer)" is pronounced as /ˈlɒŋɡər/ having **/ŋɡ/** and not just **/ŋ/** in Standard Englishes. "Longer" is derived from "long" which only has **/ŋ/**.

There are some other words as well, like *younger, youngest* and the superlative form of "long": *longest* = **/ŋg/**

And those which have only **/ŋ/**: *ringer, hanger, banger*.

I read this answer ([“English” pronounced as /ˈɪŋlɪʃ/ ING-LISH [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539834/english-pronounced-as-%CB%88%C9%AA%C5%8Bl%C9%AA%CA%83-ing-lish/539837#539837)) and it suggests:

> Word-internal [ŋg] mostly remained (as in finger, anger), but an originally word-final -ng- that becomes word-internal only as the result of the addition of certain suffixes is pronounced [ŋ] (e.g. singing, singer).
>
> The -ng- in English is not word-final, and -lish is not a suffix here, so it isn't expected to be pronounced [ŋ] according to the pronunciation patterns of the most commonly described dialects.

The **er** is a suffix in both "longer" and "singer" but they are pronounced differently.

Why is "singer" not pronounced as /ˈsɪ**ŋɡ**ər/ or "longer" as /ˈlɒ**ŋ**ər/?

Is "longer" an exception to this rule or there is a specific reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strong /strɔːŋ/ → stronger /strɔːŋɡər/ - Why do we have to put an extra /g/ in front of /ər/? Is it a rule?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288116/strong-str%c9%94%cb%90%c5%8b-%e2%86%92-stronger-str%c9%94%cb%90%c5%8b%c9%a1%c9%99r-why-do-we-have-to-put-an-extra-g-in-f)

Comment: I have heard singer pronounced the opposite way in some dialects/accents in the UK.

Comment: This is the reason for the apostrophe in the name of the actress Lupita Nyong'o. It indicates that there is no hard "g".

Comment: Why do you think the relevant parts of the words are pronounced differently?  Of course there are many variant pronounciations of any English word, but in mainstream US English, they certainly sound the same to me.

Comment: Worthy of note is that some US English speakers pronounce ‘longer’ and ‘younger’ without the additional ‘g’ sound.

Comment: Duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/288116/365490

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Singer* and *longer* both end in the letters *-er,* but they don't end in the same suffix: *singer* ends in the *-er* suffix that forms agent nouns, while *longer* ends in the *-er* suffix that forms comparative adjectives.

This is the reason why I included the word "certain" in "the addition of certain suffixes".

Words ending in the comparative suffix *-er* or the superlative suffix *-est* could be said to be an exception as a class to the general pattern of suffixes not altering the pronunciation of [ŋ].

But there are very few words with the relevant sequence *-ng-* + comparative *-er*, since there aren't many monosyllabic adjectives ending in [ŋ]. In fact, there are only three adjectives that have inflected forms with [ŋg]: *younger/youngest, stronger/strongest, longer/longest* (all common). The adjective *wrong,* also common, has what I think are uncommon inflected forms that are pronounced according to dictionaries and my own intuition with [ŋ]: *wronger, wrongest.* So it's arguable whether there is a regular exception for the category of comparative and superlative forms, or it's just a matter of these specific three adjectives having special comparative and superlative forms.

The same distribution of [ŋ] and [ŋg] in adjective forms is described (and prescribed) by John Walker in his *Critical Pronouncing Dictionary* (1803) so it seems to have been around in its usual modern form for a least a couple of centuries. But Walker also mentions variation in his time, saying that in Ireland comparative adjective forms like *longer* are "generally pronounced" with [ŋ] rather than [ŋg] ([lxxxi](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Critical_Pronouncing_Dictionary_and_Ex/PzVWAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22wrongest%22+%22strongest%22+%22longest%22+%22youngest%22&pg=PP83&printsec=frontcover)).

In informal off-the-cuff formations, you can sometimes find comparatives or superlatives formed from words of two or more syllables ending in *-ing*, which I believe like *wronger, wrongest* would not be pronounced with [ŋg], but with [ŋ]: things like *[charmingest](https://www.onelook.com/?w=charmingest)* and *[boringer](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Boringer).*

Comment: Another adjective ending /ŋ/ is *headlong*, although I can't find any usage in print of *headlonger* rather than *more headlong*.

Comment: Ginger bread. Or just ginger.

Comment: _Long_ is a verb, too, and thus subject to the agentive _-er_, which does not change /ŋ/ to /ŋɡ/. So one who longs is a _longer_, while the comparative of _long_ is also spelled "longer", but _longer_ the comparative adjective doesn't rhyme with _longer_ the agentive noun. Rather like _singer_ not rhyming with _finger_, and for much the same reasons.

Answer (score 6):

When you know that the agent noun "one that longs" (longer) is pronounced without a **/ɡ/**: /lɒŋ.ə/ (*Longman Pronunciation Dictionary*, RP), this  might be explained cursorily by referring to the  fickleness of usage .

Comment: Great Example! I didn't even think of it and of course, this example follows the rule explained in Herrison's answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My daughter who attended the British School of Paris was reprimanded for saying ‘singing’ with a soft g sound, her teacher insisting on sin ng ing. Fortunately my daughter had the presence of mind to respond that in « Singing in the Rain » they got it wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm having trouble following this. Do you mean your daughter pronounced it to sound exactly like being slightly burned = 'singeing'? In IPA that is /'sɪndʒ iŋ/.  Or are you saying she pronounced it like 'finger' /fɪŋ gr/? or are you saying like without the voiced velar stop after the velar nasal, /sɪŋ r/?

Answer (score -1):

Don't know what you mean by "standard Englishes", as they sound just the same to me.  Perhaps your ears are better at picking up subtle differences?

In any case, you need to remember that English spelling is only approximately - sometimes very approximately - phonetic.  Words are spelled the way they are because the standard version is the one approximation, usually of many, that won out when people started compiling & using dictionaries.

Comment: I'm not sure how it answers the question. This question is more about 'pronunciation' than 'spelling'. Also, I have to take issue with your second point, it's true in general that English spelling is not phonetic, but the vast majority of words (spelling) **do** have predictable pronunciations.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul: You're correct in saying that it doesn't answer the question, because there really is no rational answer to the question, other than "just because".