# What will happen if I attach the suffixes "-ize" and "-ify" to a word that end in /ŋ/? Will they make it [ŋg]?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, linguistics

This question is related to my previous question: [Why does “singer” have /ŋ/ and “longer” have /ŋg/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/551070/why-does-singer-have-%C5%8B-and-longer-have-%C5%8Bg) but **not** a duplicate.

From Herrison's answer, I learned that the *-er* in both "singer" and "longer" is not the same:

> *Singer* and *longer* both end in the letters *-er*, but they don't end in the same suffix: *singer* ends in the *-er* suffix that forms agent nouns, while *longer* ends in the *-er* suffix that forms comparative adjectives.

Now I wonder what will happen if I attach the verb making suffixes **-ize** (e.g. material*ize*) and **-ify** (e.g. "intens*ify*") to a word that ends in /ŋ/ (say *ring*). The [ŋg] is found in middle of words such as *finger, younger, stronger* etc.

Let's say there is a word (not a verb) that ends in /ŋ/ and we want to make it a verb by adding *-ize* or *-ify* to it, will the ending /ŋ/ become [ŋg] or it will remain [ŋ]? For example, suppose I want to make "anything" a verb by adding *-ize* or *-ify* to it:

- anything /ˈɛnɪθɪŋ/ + ize = anythingize /ˈɛnɪθɪ**ŋ**aɪz/ or /ˈɛnɪθɪ**ŋg**aɪz/?
- anything /ˈɛnɪθɪŋ/ + ify = anythingify /ˈɛnɪθɪ**ŋ**ɪfaɪ/ or /ˈɛnɪθɪ**ŋg**ɪfaɪ/?

I am talking about the accents that are considered standard (Southern British and General American). In simple words, the accents in which "singer" has only [ŋ] not [ŋg]

(NOTE: I am not concerned about what meaning it would give. I am merely asking about "pronunciation").

Comment: I think it is clear to most users here that your interest is mainly on pronunciation rather than meaning :)

Comment: Pronunciation is not standard. There are many places **in England** where *singer* has [ŋg], as well as many where it doesn't.

Comment: @user66974 - That's so true! ;-) (mainly pronunciation with a smattering of etymology)

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Yes, I know that and I was talking about the varieties that are considered standard. If it's still not clear, I mean the accents in which "singer" has [ŋ] only. I will update my question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not about standard English but about coining new words.

Comment: @Greybeard - will something bad happen if you don't vote to close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These suffixes are rarely attached to a base of this form. The Oxford English Dictionary gives the following words and pronunciations (leaving out some obsolete forms):

- *diphthongize, monophthongize*  /ŋɡ/ in British English, /ŋ(ɡ)/ in American English
- *thingify* /ŋ/ in both British English and American English

The general guideline I would give is that /ŋɡ/ is unlikely with new formations, especially if the word is a "nonce formation" of the kind that is often hyphenated: if a spelling like "anything-ize" or "anything-ify" seems possible, then the pronunciation will likely not have /g/.

The same tendency to not use /g/ applies to words suffixed with *-ish,* which is somewhat more common: thus *wrongish, strongish, longish, youngish* are all given by the Oxford English Dictionary with /ŋɪʃ/.

Answer (score 1):

It could be pronounced either way. Compare *diphthongise* (*-ize*) which is derived from *diphthong* (ends in /ŋ/) and *-ise* and is mostly pronounced with [ŋ] (I've heard it pronounced [ˈdifθɒŋɡaɪz]). For *diphthongise*, [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/diphthongize) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diphthongize) give the pronunciation with [ŋ] only:

- /ˈdɪfθɒ**ŋ**ʌɪz/

However, Collins Dictionary and Dictionary.com list the pronunciation with [ŋɡ] as an alternative.

As for the suffix *-ify*, I think it can also be pronounced in both ways; with [ŋ] or [ŋɡ]. There aren't many ify-verbs that have [ŋ] before the *-ify*, the only one I've been able to find is *stringify* for which [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stringify) gives /ˈstɹɪ**ŋ**ɪfaɪ/ only.